# Warning: mysql_result(): Unable to jump to row 0 on MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I want to select an id from a table using the query:

```
$demo_id = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT id FROM demo_tbl WHERE a_val='a' and b_val='b' LIMIT 1"),0);
```

This query works perfectly if it satisfies the condition. But if there is no such record then the above mentioned error shows. I dont want to use mysql_num_rows(). Is there any way to find whether $demo_id has value or not.

Comment: mysql_* functions are deprecated use PDO or mysqli.

Comment: just do an if statement and suppress the error. mysql_result will return `false` if there is no return value

Comment: @Enstage Thank you for your reply. I understand. But is there any way to find it using any other  mysql functions.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-result.php

Comment: You'll have more overhead suppressing errors than you will checking the number of rows. Why not use a query that always returns a result, like wrapping that in a `coalesce`.  Also above ^ `mysql_*` is deprecated in every currently supported version, and completely removed in 7.0.  See http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

Comment: @hungrykoala It's not working.

Comment: Thank you guys. Actually there was no error. It was just a warning message. So I suppressed the warning using @ symbol and checked if $demo_id is false. And thank you @ hungrykoala.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(!$demo_id){
//no return
}else{
//demo_id has value
}
```

base on the manual:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-result.php

Answer (score 0):

if you  are not using `mysqli_num_rows()` then you try this

```
if (empty($demo_id)) { 
    echo 'No results found'; 
} else {
    echo implode($demo_id);
}
```

and also i mention that don't use `mysql_*`.. you should use `mysqli_*`
[Mysqli_* manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)